# after updating to 2.10.1 webApp does not work

Tags: .net, linux, mono, ubuntu-10.04

Im new in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

### When i run web application error occur:

Server Error in '/mywebApp' Application

Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Description: HTTP 500. Error processing request.

Stack Trace:

**System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at System.Web.SessionState.SessionInProcHandler.GetItemInternal (System.Web.HttpContext context, System.String id, System.Boolean& locked, System.TimeSpan& lockAge, System.Object& lockId, System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateActions& actions, Boolean exclusive) [0x00000] in :0** 
Version information: Mono Runtime Version: 2.10.8.1 (Debian 2.10.8.1-1~dhx1~lucid1); ASP.NET Version: 2.0.50727.1433

Comment: I have the same problem for Mono 2.10.9, running on Mac OS 10.5.8. There is some problem with the in-process session state handler, but I don't know what.

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to use out-process session state:

1. Open a console and type "asp-state4" to start the server.
2. Open your web.config and add under `<system.web>`:

   ```
   <sessionState mode="StateServer"
       stateConnectionString="tcpip=localhost:42424"
       stateNetworkTimeout="100"/>
   ```